# Experimenting with cong in the Idris REPL

Tags: proof, idris

**TL;DR: I'd like an example or two of using `cong` in the Idris REPL to help me understand it better.**

The generic equality type is conceptually defined like so:

```
data (=) : a -> b -> Type where
  Refl : x = x
```

When I first encountered this, I was very confused by the syntax. (I kept thinking of `=` as an operator rather than a type.) But playing around with it in the REPL helped me to understand. For example, we can declare types to represent false equalities:

```
λ> 2 + 2 = 5
4 = 5 : Type
λ> 2 = "wombat"
2 = "wombat" : Type
```

However, the only constructor for the `=` is Refl, and we can only use it when the two arguments are equal.

```
λΠ> the (4 = 4) Refl
Refl : 4 = 4
λΠ> the (4 = 5) Refl
... type mismatch
```

So now I'm trying to understand `cong` by experimenting with it in the REPL.
The function `cong` proves that if two values are equal, applying a
function to them produces an equal result. I found the definition.

```
  cong : {f : t -> u} -> (a = b) -> f a = f b
  cong Refl = Refl
```

So, for example, if I define...

```
λ> :let twoEqTwo = the (2 = 2) Refl
defined
```

...then I expected to be able to show that adding 1 to both sides results in another equality.

```
λΠ> :let ty = (S 2 = S 2)
defined
λΠ> the ty (cong twoEqTwo)
    ...type mismatch
```

**Can anyone show me an example or two of using `cong` in the REPL?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `2`s are of the wrong type. They have defaulted to the type `Integer` in `twoEqTwo`, because they have no other constraints. See, an unconstrained `2`:

```
idris> 2
2 : Integer
```

Yet, in `ty`, you say `S 2`. The `S` forces the whole thing to work in `Nat`:

```
idris> S 2
3 : Nat
```

Make `twoEqTwo` work in `Nat`, too:

```
idris> :let twoEqTwo = the (the Nat 2 = 2) Refl
idris> the (S 2 = S 2) twoEqTwo
Refl : 3 = 3
```

Note that type inference can sort this out itself if you let it see the entire expression:

```
idris> the (S 2 = S 2) (cong (the (2 = 2) Refl))
Refl : 3 = 3
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense; thank you! I understand now how to use cong.